# Bottom Tabbar touchables are red in react-native inspector and not clickable

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-debugger

I'm facing a weird issue with my react-native application which i'm not able to solve.

I use react-navigation in my app and @react-navigation/bottom-tabs for the bottom tab navigator.

While developing the iOS version everything worked fine, but in the android version i'm not able to click the buttons in the bottom tab bar.

I'll already checked the "touchables" from the bottom bar with the inspector from the react-native debugger and i recognized a "red area" over the buttons.

Someone knows where this comes from and if this is the reason for blocking the buttons?

[image]

Comment: its expo 44 ? if so try "expo eject" then run it witout expo, and its fixed, in Expo 44 there is a lot of BUGS that prevents touches or hiding Animated views


Often when something works on iOS and android not it means zIndex problem or Absolute position problem if "expo eject" doesnt help 

its hard to tell without code

Comment: no, unfortunately its the react-native-cli

Comment: then only option here is to provide simple code example if passible, u can comment whole screen content but make sure your whole app is wrapped to this ```<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>``` from ```import {GestureHandlerRootView} from "react-native-gesture-handler";```, cuz this can be issue too if u using latest navigation version

Comment: No, unfortunately its still not working even with the GestureHandlerRootView

Comment: so then provide demo stack with this problem and we can help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the logic is really nested, so its not really easy to provide an example. But i upgraded react-navigation to the latest version and now the problem seems gone